# Как указать сортировку по ID по умолчанию в конкретной или всех таблицах в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Например, есть таблица `Users`. Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы любая выборка включающая столбей ID сортировалась по нему. Или мне не избежать того, что в каждом запросе я должен указывать порядок сортировки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой возможности нет. Пока в запросе не указан явно `order by` PostgreSQL может возвращать строки в любом порядке.

Comment: Я работал до этого с `mysql` и `mariadb` и таких проблем не наблюдал...

Comment: @doox911, значит плохо работали. У них поведение аналогично - пока нет order by - данные могут быть возвращены в любом порядке. База ничего в этом случае не обещает и наблюдаемое совпадение лишь случайность

Comment: Я так понимаю, что я не плохо работал) А в `InnoDB`  выводится в порядке `PRIMARY KEY`.  Вот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8746712/10876086. И в моём случае - это было совпадение.

Comment: InnoDB  физически кластеризован в порядке первичного ключа. Потому seqscan делает видимость результата отсортированного в том же порядке. Сделайте поиск по другому индексу - и порядка уже не будет. insert-only табличка в postgresql тоже будет при seqscan делать вид, что отсортирована в порядке записи данных. Но это опять же лишь совпадение.